# Hojas de calculo .ods importadas a python

Tags: python

Tengo muchas dudas con respecto al funcionamiento y el alcance de las hojas de calculo en python, disculpen si mi pregunta es algo totalmente sins sentido.

La hoja de calculo importada tiene todo perfectos, sus valores son correctos, pero se deben sustituir en S11 cada valor para que me arroje la misma cantidad de valores como resultado, lo pude hacer sin problemas antes con un "array" pero pensaba que la hoja de calculo funcionaria igual que un array, no soy muy avanzado programando, gracias por su atención.
este es el error arrojado.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upa-010/Escritorio/python/prueba.py", line 39, in <module>
    Er1=(Er0-(f(Er0)/Df(Er0)))
  File "/home/upa-010/Escritorio/python/prueba.py", line 33, in f
    Y=((1-S11*(tan(B*d)**2)+2*j*sqrt(Er)*tan(B*d)-Er*(S11+1)))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Pow'
[Finished in 3.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/upa-010/Escritorio/python/prueba.py"]
[dir: /home/upa-010/Escritorio/python]
[path: /home/upa-010/bin:/home/upa-010/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
#paquetes
from numpy import*
from Tkinter import*
import ttk
import Image, ImageTk
import pandas as pd
import ezodf
from cmath import*
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import ezodf
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
from math import*
import uno
from pyexcel_ods import get_data
from sympy import*

#Leer archivo ODS
hoja=get_data("SaTr11.ods")
import json
S11A=json.dumps(hoja)
S11=array(S11A)
#METODO DE NEWTON 
#Longitud de onda
L=0.55       
#Grosor                
d=4*10**-3                   
j=1j  
print(S11)                       

def f(Er):
    B=(2*pi*sqrt(Er)/L)
    Y=((1-S11*(tan(B*d)**2)+2*j*sqrt(Er)*tan(B*d)-Er*(S11+1)))
    return Y
def Df(Er):
    return (((j*tan(2*pi*(d**2)*sqrt(Er)/L))/sqrt(Er))+((2*pi*j*(cos(2*pi*(d**2)*sqrt(Er)/L)**-2))/L)-((2*pi*d*(S11-1)*tan(2*pi*d*sqrt(Er)/L)*(cos(2*pi*d*sqrt(Er)/L)**-2))/L*sqrt(Er))-S11-1)
Er0=5
for i in range(1,100):
    Er1=(Er0-(f(Er0)/Df(Er0)))
Er0=Er1
#FINAL DE METODO DE NEWTON
```

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con la traza completa del error para que sepamos donde falla y también un ejemplo de qué valores funcionan y cuales fallan. También tienes un poco de jaleo en los imports y el indentado tmb está regular pero puede ser por el copy&paste. Revísalo

Comment: Tienes un error de código, probablemente por el enredo que tiene tus nombres de variables se alejan de cualquier tipo de estándar de buenas practicas. Estas haciendo una operación aritmetica entre una variable que posee una funcion, en este caso Pow, con un numero. Te recomiendo debugear o imprimir los valores de tus variables para identificar cual de ellas posee valores inconsistentes. Intenta ir de a pasos cortos para asegurarte que las variables poseen los valores que deberían.

Comment: se que no es la forma mas adecuada de hacerlo, pero las variables están correctas, ya lo he probado, pero tengo algunas dudas con el tipo que entra en el archivo ods, son números así (4.962000000000000E+008) ya que eso viene directamente de un estudio previo, no se si sea la forma del numero o algo mas.